# jQuery prompt and ajax from PHP system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a system running in PHP. I would like to generate some reports for the system using iReport (JasperReport).

What I want to do is:
By clicking a button in the system, a dialog box pop-up, entering the parameter.
Then the parameter will pass to the report generating program (in PHP) the access the iReport, then report in PDF format will shown on screen.

I have created the button, and the button can call to the JS function. However with the following code, I cannot get the dialog box pop-up and hence the ajax cannot process as expected.

```
function ajax_Report() {
     jQuery.prompt(  { state0: {
     title: 'Please enter the selected product', 
     html:'<label>Product Code: <input type="text" name="PrdCode"></label>',
     buttons: { 'Confirm':true, 'Cancel': false}, 
     focus: 1 ,     
     submit:function(e,confirm,m,data){ 
        if(confirm) {      
        new Ajax.Request(
            "report/Rpt.php", 
            {queue:{position:"end", scope:"command"}, 
                method:"post", 
                postBody:"PrdCode="+data.PrdCode, 
                onComplete:function (response) {
                    $("status").style.display = "none";
                        $("ListViewContents").innerHTML= response.responseText;
                        $('basicsearchcolumns').innerHTML = '';
                        $('allselectedboxes').value='';
                        $('excludedRecords').value='';
                }
            }
        ); 
        }
    }
}})
}
```

Thanks in advance. Anyone with any help will be much appreciate.

Comment: when the function invokes? i mean where is the function calls.

Comment: I got a button with: <input class="crmbutton small edit" type="button" value="{$button_label}" onclick="return ajax_Report()"/> to call the function